# Trying to get the difference in hours between two dates

Tags: php

I'm trying to get the time difference between the current date and another date in php but i'm getting wrong results.
Her's my code so far:

```
function hoursDifference($date)
{
   return round((time()- strtotime($date))/3600);
}
```

The input date is: 2016-03-20 03:55:51 but the current time is using the 24 hours format, so the H is 15 instead of 3 and the function returns a correct 12 hour time difference. How can I fix this?

Comment: Take a look at [DateTime::diff](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php)

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3923228/2087463

Answer (score 0):

For 12 hour Date instead of 24 hour Date use a Lower case 'h'.
You should also take a look at [DateTime::diff](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php) like @fusion3k mentioned.

[This link](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_date_date.asp) should also help you on which parameters you can use on your $date.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
 function hoursDifference($date)
 {
  return round(strtotime(date("Y-m-d h:i:s")) - strtotime($date))/3600);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

use the DateTime Object:
http://php.net/manual/de/class.datetime.php

```
echo hoursDifference("2016-03-20 12:13:12");

function hoursDifference($date)
{
    $d = new DateTime($date);
    $now = new DateTime();   
    $iv = $now->diff($d);
    return $iv->h;
}
```